# how to keep a class that extends and implements an interface with Proguard

Tags: java, proguard

i need to keep all class that extend com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport and implements a custom interface .

when i try this

```
-keepnames public class * extends com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport implements com.company.project.utils.Constantes {
 *; 
 }
```

i get the following error :

> error expecting openning  '{' at 'implements'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If memory serves, you can specify classes that extend another class OR classes that implement an interface, but not both. The [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html) doesn't make this particularly clear but it is implied there.

There are a couple ways around this, assuming that it isn't sufficient for you to just specify one or the other:

- Create an empty 'marker' interface and have the classes you want to keep extend that.
- Add a static (can be `private static final` if you like) marker field to each of the classes you want to keep, and specify that in the -keep options.
- Bite the bullet and just list the names of all the classes you want to keep.

**EDIT**

Another option would be to create a class like this:

```
public abstract class Foo extends com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport implements com.company.project.utils.Constantes {
    // ...
}
```

Then, have all the classes you want to keep extend that class. Then you just need to specify `* extends Foo` in the -keep options.

Comment: thanks , but this limitation kinda sucks , it makes obfuscation realy unpractical .

Comment: Thought of another possible solution, so have updated my answer. Honestly though, your requirement that the classes both extend a particular class AND implement a particular interface is pretty rare.

Comment: the thing is , i want to preserve all Action class and they both extends ActionSupport and implements Constantes.
i would've loved to be able to keep'em just by specifiying 

-keepnames public class * extends com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport

but proguard needs the complete signature , the documentation implies that you can keep a class that extends "or" implements , i think they meant and XOR  there .

Comment: IIRC `-keepnames public class * extends com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport` ought to work just fine?

Comment: it doesn't work ,proguard doesn't keep classes that extend that both extend Action and implement some interface , cuz the class signature doesn't fully fit the template specified.

Comment: ahh i just retested  -keepnames public class * extends com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport 

was enough to keep the class i wanted to keep . you were right .

Comment: Thought I was going mad for a moment there. Glad you got it sorted. :)